# Symfony 2.6 - How to validate non-entity form using validation.yml?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a form which does not represent any Entity object, however, I would like to validate this form, but for some reasons (for example clean code etc), it must be done by using `validation.yml` file.

I store my form object in **`\\src\ZaquPL\MyCustomBundle\Form\Type\MyCustomFormType.php`**. Moreover, I created **`validation.yml`** file:

```
ZaquPL\MyCustomBundle\Form\Type\MyCustomFormType:
    properties:
        myField:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

But my form is not validated. **`$form->isValid()`** always return **`true`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's not possible. Validators placed in annotations or yml file, should be connected with entity object, not with form type.

But there is small workaround.

You can create your own FormBuilder service. His method should get as argument your FormType, then he will rewrite your FormType to get form created by method 'createFormBuilder': [Symfony form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form). Then in this service you can read validation file and add validators in this way:
[Symfony documentation - adding validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation)

It's really time-consuming and I think that's better to attach validators to your entity.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not needed and an ugly code chabge to internal services

Answer (score 4):

I think is link contain the perfect example as you want. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

You see there is a model named as Registration which is not an entity. Here it is
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html#embedding-the-user-form-into-a-registration-form

The directory of the of this class is src/Acme/AccountBundle/Form/Model/Registration.php, This can be validated perfectly as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an plain php object as model class and use this as data object in your createForm(). Then you can create the validation.yml on this simple model object.

Comment: I agree with this comment. Simply do not make an entity, but only a model (which is not persisted to db), and add the class to validation.yml. Then you can validate in using validator service.